# QT Quick Model Provider?

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2, model-view

I have QT application that has a number of panels that I would like to flexibly load a run time.

Instead of each View having a predefined singleton Model declared is it possible to declare a singleton "model provider" and have it return a model based on the fields requested by the view?

Is this a viable approach?
I'm thinking: Q_INVOKEABLE that returns a model, then hook the change signals at runtime to update the view?